# Solution to a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections, quadratic-forms

I'm trying to find a closed form solution of the following quadratic form for $x$.

$x^{T}Dx = c$

where $c$ is just a constant placeholder for some terms on the other side.

I know that, because $D$ is positive semi-definite, this equation describes a level curve of an ellipsoid in $x$, which gives me hope that there exists a closed form solution of the form $x = \frac{a\pm  \sqrt{z}}{b}$, for some $a, z, b$ (which may be matrices or vectors).

Do you know if this solution exists and if so how it is determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this in a basis with respect to which $D$ is diagonal.  Then I think you can see better what is going on.  You can do this using a basis of orthogonal vectors.  Also, if $D$ is positive definite, you might find the Cholesky factorization less computationally intensive.

Comment: That sort of helped - I can see that there's a rotation and then scaling involved, but I'm still unsure as to how to solve for $x$ explicitly. I end up with a summation of orthogonal vectors (axes) and eigenvalues equaling my constant term.

Comment: Write $D = Q^{-1} S Q$ where $Q$ is orthogonal, and $S$ is diagonal with non-negative entries $s_1,\dots,s_n$.  Then the equation is $\sum_{k=1}^n s_k y_k^2 = c$, where $y_k = Q x_k$.