# Binary solutions to quadratic form with indefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, matrix-decomposition

I have a $n\times n$ real symmetric indefinite non-zero matrix $A$ where diagonal elements are all the same.

Assume $x \in \{-1, 1\}^n$. There are two questions I'm tackling:

> 1. *Is this statement true:* there exists such an A where $x^TAx = 0, \forall x$.
> 2. Say I have found an $x$ such that $x^TAx = 0$. Is there an analytical (or computationally efficient) way to construct from $x$, a solution $\hat{x} \in \{-1,1\}^n$ such that $\hat{x}^T A \hat{x} \neq 0$?

There are related questions but the insights there didn't help me much: [zeros of $x^*Ax$, a quadratic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198427/zeros-of-xax-a-quadratic-form)
[Solution to a quadratic form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597735/solution-to-a-quadratic-form)

Any suggestions, will help. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to find symmetric $\rm A$ such that $\rm x^{\top} A x = 0$ for all $\rm x \in \{\pm 1\}^n$, then you have $2^n$ linear equations in $\binom{n+1}{2}$ unknowns.

Comment: And half of the equations are redundant. Hence, $2^{n-1}$ equations.

Comment: Which means that the system is *underdetermined* when $n \in \{2,3,4\}$.